# Different limits of string theory parameters

Tags: string-theory, physical-constants, ads-cft

So in (perturbative) String theory, it is my understanding that we have the following parameters (taking natural units).

The string length : $\ell_s$, which appears in front of the world-sheet action, and sets the string tension (usually we use $\alpha'=\ell_s^2$, but anyway).

The planck length : $\ell_p$. Usually I think we assume that $\ell_s \approx \ell_p$, but I don't think it is necessary.

The string coupling : $g_s$. This gives "interaction strength" of the scattering diagrams, according to their genus. So it governs the contribution of "loop diagrams" in string scatterings.

Now, assume we put the strings on an AdS background. This adds a scale, which is the AdS radius, $\ell$.

My question concerns the various limit of the parameters. We can build 3 independent dimensionless parameters :
($g_s$, $\ell/\ell_s$, $\ell_s/\ell_p$).

Now, (in the context of AdS/CFT), we say that the "Classical (super)gravity" limit is obtained for $g_s\ll 1$, $\ell/\ell_s \gg 1$. And I can kinda see why : for $g_s\ll 1$ we have "classical strings", as we have no loop diagrams. For $\ell\ll \ell_s$, we have no "stringy physics", and so we reduce to Einstein gravity. However, it is unclear to me how $\ell_s/\ell_p$ affects the theory.

My question is how each of those three dimensionless parameters affect the theory that we have. Just as an example of my confusion, $\ell/\ell_s$ governs "stringy corrections", thus a theory with $\ell/\ell_s\ll 1$ can be described without strings. But what would it mean then to have this AND $g_s\gg 1$ ?

Comment: Limit $\ell_s\to \infty$ with finite $\ell$ is not only Einstein gravity but the theory of infinite number of massless higher spin fields (Vasiliev's theory).